# Compare Dictionary Values that belongs to different keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionaries inside a list like this:

```
sample_dict = [{1: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], \
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], \
                    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]}, \
               {2: [[3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [1, 2, 3, 6, 10], []]}]
```

Now, I would like to check the key `1`'s first value in the list with key `2`'s first value. 
something like this,

Compare Values (first value of list of lists of key 1)

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

with (first value of list of lists of key 2)

```
[3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

If they are a match I would like to append it to a new list `matching_list`, if not I would to append non-matching values into another list `non_matching_list`.

This is what I tried so far,

```
matching_list = []
non_matching_list = []

for each_dict in sample_dict:
    current_dict_values = []
    for key, value_list in each_dict.items():
        temp_dict_values = []

        for value in value_list:
            temp_dict_values.append(value)

            .... don't know how to keep track of key 1's first list of lists values.
```

I was thinking of creating a temporary list to keep track of key `1` list values, but I am stuck and not sure how to proceed.

My final output should be like this:

```
matching_list = [[3,4,6,7,8,9,10], [1,2,3], []]
non_matching_list = [[1,2,5,11],[4,5,6,10],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

How can I achieve my output? Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by converting `lists` to `sets` to make operations like `symmetric_difference()` and `intersection()` for your `non_matching_list` and `matching_list` respectively.

Here is one of the solutions:

```
matching_list, non_matching_list = [], []

for lists1, lists2 in zip(sample_dict[0].values(), sample_dict[1].values()):
    for l1, l2 in zip(lists1, lists2):
        matching_list.append(list(set(l1) & set(l2)))
        non_matching_list.append(list(set(l1).symmetric_difference(set(l2))))
```

Note that using `set(l1) & set(l2)` is same as `set(l1).intersection(set(l2))`, so basically it's an intersection operation here.

I'm also using builtin `zip()` function to aggregate elements from each of the iterables ( both lists ).